# How to define a custom template for entering a partial derivative?

Tags: formatting

I want to define a custom template for entering a partial derivative.
For example, When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>, I want to get

[image]

To make my template, I followed a previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327411/is-there-a-way-around-using-and-for-part-in-mathematica?lq=1) that made a shortcut for `[[`: I opened the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file and added

```
Item[
  KeyEvent["'", Modifiers -> {Control,Shift}], 
  FrontEndExecute[{
    FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
      "Derivative[\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder]]
        [\[SelectionPlaceholder]][\[Placeholder], \[Placeholder]]", 
      After]}]],
```

But, when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, I only get

[image]

Is there any way to achieve my full purpose?

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting is what you told the front-end to provide. Further, it is completely equivalent to the form you want -- it's just in raw input form rather than standard input form. In fact, you can convert it to your desired form by selecting it and keying <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on some systems).

Comment: Hi, your method is good enough. However, when I entered the combination key which you mentioned, it selected the entire inputcell automatically. I have to use the direct key to return to the cell. If I input a long expression and forget the detail, the cell will be overlapped. Can we customize typesetting in Mathematica?